# 504 Gateway Timeout on ElasticBeanstalk for PHP when connecting Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When a user connects to my web app using their Facebook login, the server wouldn't redirect back because of the 504 error it got caught along the way.

It works normally in my local testing environment, but it has that problem on my staging server where I use Amazon Elastic Beanstalk as a platform.

Any idea how I could fix that?

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-error-message.html

> Description: Indicates that the load balancer closed a connection because a request did not complete within the idle timeout period.
>
> Cause 1: The application takes longer to respond than the configured idle timeout.
>
> Solution 1: Monitor the HTTPCode_ELB_5XX and Latency CloudWatch metrics. If there is an increase in these metrics, it could be due to the application not responding within the idle timeout period. For details about the requests that are timing out, enable access logs on the load balancer and review the 504 response codes in the logs that are generated by Elastic Load Balancing. If necessary, you can increase your back-end capacity or increase the configured idle timeout so that lengthy operations (such as uploading a large file) can complete.
>
> Cause 2: Registered instances closing the connection to Elastic Load Balancing.
>
> Solution 2: Enable keep-alive settings on your EC2 instances and set the keep-alive timeout to greater than or equal to the idle timeout settings of your load balancer.

Comment: possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672302/aws-beanstalk-nodejs-how-to-override-60s-timeout-of-nginx/63676954?noredirect=1#comment125499272_63676954