# aws beanstalk nodejs: how to override 60s timeout of nginx

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to increase the default timeout of nginx in a nodejs environment in AWS elastic beanstalk, i'm following this guide: https://medium.com/swlh/using-ebextensions-to-extend-nginx-default-configuration-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-189b844ab6ad but it's not working, if i upload my application i receive this error Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-xxxxxxxxxx'. Aborting the operation. any suggestion?
i'm trying to use .ebextension and this is the code of my 01-timeout.config file

```
files:
"/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-timeout.conf":
 mode: “000644”
 owner: root
 group: root
 content: |
   keepalive_timeout 600s;
   proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
   proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
   proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
   fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
   fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
container_commands:
  nginx_reload:
   command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Thanks for any help.

**Update** now the deploy it's ok, but the timeout doesn't work, it's like before with the timeout of 60s, reading the logs seems that the reload of nginx it's made, this is the message: Command nginx_reload succeeded , any clue of what is the problem?

Comment: check your elastic beanstalk logs, you may find the reason why the command failed, or maybe there is just a space missing before `nginx_reload` but not sure about that.

Comment: you were right, i found this error:2020/08/31 13:19:40 [emerg] 18127#0: unknown directive "files:" in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/01-timeout.conf:7 but how can i solve that?

Comment: it may be the indentation, try  indenting the `files:` content by two spaces and also indenting everything under `/etc/nginx.... ` except `container_commands`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.ebextension method is not working now.Please try `.platform` method.

Please create a folder called `.platform` in your project root folder.

```
.platform/
         nginx/
              conf.d/
                    timeout.conf
         00_myconf.config
```

Content of File 1 - `timeout.conf` (Inside `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` folder)

```
keepalive_timeout 600s;
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

Content of File 2 - `00_myconf.config` (Inside `.platform/` folder)

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

reupload your application and see the changes.

Comment: This solution has not worked for me. Is there a waiting period before the changes take effect? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check and confirm the extensions of the files (.conf and .config)

Comment: Yes I've checked and they have their respective extensions (.conf and .config)

Answer (score 3):

Your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-timeout.conf` is ignored because this is a valid file for EB platforms based on Amazon Linux 1 (AL2). However, it seems to me that you are using new, current versions of EB based Amazon Linux 2 (EB).

For AL2, the nginx settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in the "Reverse proxy configuration" section.

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
keepalive_timeout 600s;
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

Manual restart of nginx using `sudo service nginx reload` couldn't be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Please try it like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-timeout.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      keepalive_timeout 600s;
      proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
      proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
      proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
      fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

container_commands:
  nginx_reload:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Comment: i tried your snippet but unfortunately failed the deploy of application

Comment: did it fail with the same error? Also maybe you should use `"` instead of `”` for `000644`

Comment: you were right!! the problem was the character of double quote for the 000644!! your solution works perfectly!! thank you so much

Comment: update: now deploy correctly but the timeout doesn't work, it's like before with the timeout, reading the logs seems that the reload of nginx it's made, this is the message: Command nginx_reload succeeded , any clue of what is the problem?