# Unable to increase the timeout on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to increase the timeout on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk but I still get a 504 Gateway timeout.

Here's what I've done so far:

.ebextensions/timeouts.config:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elb:policies
    option_name: ConnectionSettingIdleTimeout
    value: 940
  - namespace: aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
    option_name: IdleTimeout
    value: 940

files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.timeouts.conf":
      mode: "644"
      owner: "root"
      group: "root"
      content: |
        client_header_timeout   5;
        client_body_timeout     10;
        send_timeout            940;
        proxy_connect_timeout   2;
        proxy_read_timeout      940;
        proxy_send_timeout      10;

container_commands:
  01_update_nginx:
    command: "sudo sed -i 's/keepalive_timeout  65;/keepalive_timeout  940;/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
  02_restart_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx restart"
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 10 --timeout 935 --graceful-timeout 935 main:app
```

Despite this, I still get a "504 Gateway Time-out" after exactly 60.1 seconds.

What am I missing that should make it work?

Comment: In theory you've got what's needed there. Have you checked the ELB timeout value has changed after you've deployed that config change? But what requires such a long time?

Comment: Are you using EB platform based on Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: Will this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/63676954/7532917

Comment: I note your sed command replaces a default timeout of 65 but your observed timeout is 60, which suggests you might be looking for the wrong string to replace?

Comment: @Marcin I'm using Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: @F_SO_K Interesting! I'll try that. (I'm kind of shooting in the dark here, I don't have a clue of the structure of the nginx conf file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.timeouts.conf` does not work because this is a valid file for EB platforms based on **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1). However, it as confirmed in the comments, you are using  AL2.

For AL2, the nginx settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in the "Reverse proxy configuration" section.

Therefore, you could try creating the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` file with the content of:

```
client_header_timeout   5;
client_body_timeout     10;
send_timeout            940;
proxy_connect_timeout   2;
proxy_read_timeout      940;
proxy_send_timeout      10;
```

Comment: That was it indeed! And I so much prefer this rather than restarting Nginx on deploys! Thank you!

Comment: AM2 with Corretto uses the `.platform` config path, but `.ebextensions` works on **Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.10.2** for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to post something slightly more updated; [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63772786's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63772786%27s) answer worked for me.

The big "aha!" was creating a `.platform/nginx/conf.d/nginx.custom.conf` file with the contents. Laid out.

You can run `nginx -T` to ensure the file contents were adopted by nginx.

I also kept an .ebextension file with:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
    option_name: IdleTimeout
    value: 180

container_commands:
  01_restart_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```